# Visual-Studio/XCode Interface Builder, C Sharp App not relaunching its window

Tags: c#, xcode, visual-studio, window, apple-m1

I hope someone can help me.

I am currently learning C# and have written my first app for macbooks (we use them at work).

I wrote the app in visual studio and XCode interface builder.

Almost everything works except for one thing.
When I close the app, with the red cross (top left), the app window closes, but the app continues to run in the dock.

Unfortunately, when I click on the app in the dock, nothing happens. I  have to close the app in the dock and then restart it so that it runs normal again.

Is this because I built the app in debug?
Or is there any way to fix this?

I can't build the app as a release at the moment unfortunately because then a signing error comes up while starting the app (code signature invalid).

Thank you very much.

Edit1: I've realized that programs for macbooks dont really close.
Closing the program with red cross (top left), closes the program window but the program still runs, every other program on my mac is doing that.
But if you click at them in the dock the program windows reappears, the window of my program is not reappearing. Only after really closing the program and reopening it the program window of my app launches again.
So there is still a problem.

Edit2: The signing fails because i need an apple developer account.

Edit3: I've build a release build and signed it successfully.
Sadly even in the release build this problems exits.

Edit4: I use an Apple M1 Pro and Visual Studio for Mac 17.4.1 and XCode 14.1.

---

I've solved the issue by adding:

```
public override bool ApplicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(NSApplication sender)    {  
      return true;    
}
```

into AppDelegate.cs. Now my app is closing after i press the red cross, i prefer this a lot more than letting the app run in the dock.

---

You can also use:

```
public override bool ApplicationShouldHandleReopen(NSApplication sender, bool hasVisibleWindows)
    {
        if (!hasVisibleWindows)
        {
            var sb = NSStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);//Main.storyboard
            var controller = sb.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier("MainWindow") as NSWindowController;// "MainWindow" is the Storyboard ID in WindowController of Main.storyboard. 
            controller.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(this);//You can change this window(controller.Window) if you have another window in your project
        }
        return true;
    }
```

to let the app run in the dock and the window reappear after closing it.

Comment: Hello, has your problem been solved?

Comment: Yes it has been solved.